# Query elastic search using a single query against differing JSON path

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to perform an address search against a field building number ,this information can appear in different json path depending on the type of that location ,if there is only one building in a premise the building number appears in the JSON path  addresssubpath.cobnu.cobnunum ,if its a big university campus and has building in many different private roads inside it ,it appears in the JSON path addresssubpath.coprd.cobnu.cobnunum ,how can i write a generic query which can taken the building number as input and search against both these jsonpath values and find the exact matching result,Please advise